# how can i get output without getting _id

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The following code;

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    //get the categories
    const categories = await Category.find();
    res.send(JSON.stringify(categories));
});
```

results in the following:

```
[
   {
      "_id": "5dc408ae18e952bcfb20f46d",
      "bread": {
         "name": "Bread"
      },
      "dairy": {
         "name": "Dairy"
      },
      "vegetables": {
         "name": "Vegetables"
      },
      "Seasoning": {
         "name": "Seasoning and Spices"
      },
      "fruits": {
         "name": "Fruits"
      }
   }
]
```

However I don't want to include the `_id`. What I want is as follows:

```
[
   {
      "bread": {
         "name": "Bread"
      },
      "dairy": {
         "name": "Dairy"
      },
      "vegetables": {
         "name": "Vegetables"
      },
      "Seasoning": {
         "name": "Seasoning and Spices"
      },
      "fruits": {
         "name": "Fruits"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Read all about find(). without arguments, it will return all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Just use projection for making it work
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    //get the categories
    const categories = await Category.find({}, { _id: 0 });
    res.send(JSON.stringify(categories));
});
```